# I'm not receiving anything in my inbox I set up using ISPConfig. How do I fix this?

Tags: debian, email, postfix

Before I upgraded to Debian Stretch, I had to manually install ISP-Config and adjust a bunch of other things before I could even install it. Now, when I went to check for a new version to run on Stretch, I was relieved to learn that they had built an automated script which is on GitHub.

So, I set up my E-mail with nearly the same configuration as my old one. I thought everything was fine after that. I installed WordPress, and I've been able to get WordPress notifications, like when I tested my contact form plug-in, and a messaged popped up in my inbox.

I also verified that I could send E-mails using Roundcube and Thunderbird. I got the message in my G-mail inbox. But, when I replied to the message, I didn't see it in my server.mydomain.com inbox, and I got no error from Google about it not being delivered. Also, I didn't see any drafts, junk, or trash folders in my account following the setup of my mailbox. I have found some log entries that may or may not be helpful. I found it in `/var/log/mail.log`, which was updated recently.

```
Jun  6 15:08:07 server postfix/smtpd[30503]: warning: hostname remote.mpsukltd.com does not resolve to address 109.232.156.57
Jun  6 15:08:07 server postfix/smtpd[30503]: connect from unknown[109.232.156.57]
Jun  6 15:08:10 server postfix/smtpd[30503]: warning: unknown[109.232.156.57]: SASL LOGIN authentication failed: UGFzc3dvcmQ6
Jun  6 15:08:10 server postfix/smtpd[30503]: lost connection after AUTH from unknown[109.232.156.57]
Jun  6 15:08:10 server postfix/smtpd[30503]: disconnect from unknown[109.232.156.57] helo=1 auth=0/1 commands=1/2
```

Comment: What's your real server's name? Have you checked that your DNS records are correct?

Comment: The main domain is sensation-experience.com with the hostname server, so server.sensation-experience.com. I'm using VPS.net as my domain registrar and Cloudflare to secure it.

Comment: Lots of DNS errors. I'd suggest you ask Cloudflare for advice. See https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/server.sensation-experience.com/ and https://mxtoolbox.com/domain/sensation-experience.com/

Comment: Excellent! So is this problem resolved now? (You might want to answer your own question, or simply delete it.)

Answer (score 0):

Ah, that definitely sounds like an issue with your domain, not with anything you set up on your server.

If you find that you can send messages but aren't receiving any, chances are, you probably changed the *hostname* of your server, and you now have an issue with one or more of your domain's DNS records.

If you're using a different DNS nameserver other than your domain registrar's default nameserver, you'll need to go to their site and remove any old Mail Exchange (MX) records that had your previous hostname. You can then create a new record with the updated hostname, and then check again within a few minutes.

Your E-mail should start popping up within an hour or two.